# How to sum multiple groups in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I need to learn how to use SSRS.  If anyone knows any good tutorials please let me know.  I am following the one by Microsoft (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx) and am stuck.  I do not have the adventure works database so I am using data that I have.

I have some data that looks like this

```
Name or Salesperson     Region              State           Sales
D'Ausilio, Jaclyn E.    West & South        Alabama     0   757.595541091103    2017-07-04 12:29:12.660
D'Ausilio, Jaclyn E.    West & South        Alabama     0   831.028260564931    2017-03-29 12:29:12.660
D'Ausilio, Jaclyn E.    Great Lakes & East  Connecticut 1   406.830337252288    2017-05-22 12:29:12.660
D'Ausilio, Jaclyn E.    Great Lakes & East  Connecticut 1   945.753297444545    2017-07-07 12:29:12.660
De Loys, Karen          Great Lakes & East  Illinois    0   776.159963746314    2017-05-10 12:29:12.660
De Loys, Karen          Great Lakes & East  Illinois    0   599.717806116604    2017-06-06 12:29:12.660
```

I want totals by state and salesperson.  It looks like it can be done by the Microsoft example (Order Total and Daily Total) but I follow their instructions and it fails for me.  I do not know if certain datasets are needed and mine does not meet the criteria.  Maybe what I want to do is impossible.  Perhaps I am just missing something.  Maybe if someone can answer some questions I can figure it out.

1. The example says to add a total by right clicking on a column.  How
   does it know which field to break on when this is done?
2. Why add a group in the row groups by dragging a field as opposed to using 
   the context menu?
3. What makes a Total decide where to go?  I can add a group for Name then state.  Two columns get added and it breaks fine.  The totals go at the end of the report only.  At one point I had the totals coming up properly for state but every time I tried to add them for the Name field (sales rep) it would only show at the bottom.  Now I cant figure out how I got that done before.
4. What is the difference between Add totals for the "Row Groups", the field you wish to break on or the field that is being summed?
5. In one attempt my row groups looks like this

   Name
   --StateName
   ----Details

   And the other

   Name
   --StateName
   Details

Which is correct and / or what does that mean?  Why is details a group?  I cant find the sense in that.

The field I'm summing on doesn't exist in the database, as far as I know that shouldn't matter, but you never know.  Here's my query.

```
SELECT [Name], Region, StateName, CASE WHEN Territory = 'CT' OR Territory = 'MA' OR Territory = 'NH' OR Territory = 'VT' OR Territory = 'NY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END NorthEast, RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY, NEWID())) * 1000 + 100 AS Sales, DATEADD(d, RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY, NEWID())) * 366, GETDATE()) AS LastSale
FROM SalesRepresentatives AS SR 
INNER JOIN Sales_Regions ON SalesRep = SR.ID 
INNER JOIN States ON StateAbbreviation = Territory
ORDER BY [Name], StateName
```

EDIT: I just found something out.  When I "Add Total" by right clicking on "Sales" it magically breaks on State for the total.  When I right click on the group StateName (same as state) it only puts one total at the bottom.  This makes me think it can only break on one group for totals but I must be wrong about that.  But if you can't break for totals on a group by clicking on the group then "Add Total" how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it.  To add a total you click on the group AFTER the group you want the total for.  So if you have:

```
Name
    State
        Detail
```

To make a total for State you click on detail.  For State, you click on Name.  clicking on the Name group creates a Grand Total.  WTG Microsoft!